# Фото на сайте и авторские права

Tags: веб-дизайн, авторские-права

Беру для дизайна сайта любую понравившуюся картинку из сети (рисовать не умею вообще). Как правило, в качестве фонового изображения. Может ли такое произойти, что какой-то дядя заявит на меня, что я нарушил его авторское право на фото? И как с этим бороться?

Comment: Интересный вопрос. 

Не знаю, как по закону, а по здравому смыслу должно быть так:

*все что выложил в сеть, становится общественным достоянием.*

Бороться - видимо поддерживать пиратские партии.

Comment: о_О, я с вами полностью согласен!

Comment: мои наблюдения показывают, что если Ваш сайт никому не нужен - то скорее всего никто не будет даже дергаться. А вот если у сайта тысячи посетителей в день, на сайте что-либо продаете (и при этом зарабатываете хотя бы 10-20 долларов в день) - вот тогда Вами быстро заинтересуются, будут угрожать судами.

А так, если по честному - то проще просто обратиться к собственникам сайта и просто попросить. Если не разрешат - всегда можно поискать другую у тех, кто сговорчивее.

Comment: @KoVadim, "А так, если по честному - то проще просто обратиться к собственникам сайта и просто попросить". 

Какого сайта? Я забиваю в гугле: офигенная синяя сеточка для сайта. Мне выдает браузер все офигенные синии сеточки для сайта. Я беру самую офигенную и вставляю ее как фон для своего ресурса. Так вот я о том, что я не знаю, а вдруг эта картинка имеет авторское право и за это бесконечно синюю сетку ко мне предъявят претензии.

Comment: гугл выдает адрес сайта, где он взял эту сеточку. Но думаю, что за сеточку вряд ли кто то прицепиться. А вот за что то серьезнее - тут другое дело.

Но вот только где проходит эта грань - очень сложно.

Я думаю, что правильно будет так - если у Вас хоть чуточку серьезный проект - найдите себе юриста. И после этого это все будет его проблема.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По закону, если автор ничего не написал, **вы можете свободно таскать изображения, но с сохранением ссылки на авторство (лучше просто ссылку на сайт источник)**. Если припрётся правообладатель - вроде придётся удалить.